# using different env for different cases in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt or any sort of node stuff.I m trying to create different environment for different cases, e.g. If I want to test my app, I want the block of dev object to run (pointing to dev endpoint) etc, following is a example

```
[
 prod: {
   server: www.mysite.com,
   api: 'www.jsonplaceholder.com/'
  },
 dev: {
   server: www.internal-mysite.com,
   api: 'www.jsonplaceholder.com/'
  }
]
```

so when I do `npm run dev`, it run the app with those endpoints I know that `.env` won't allowed objects or array so I cannot use that .I have tried `dotenv` but not much help I can get out of it, I tried watching [this](https://codecourse.com/watch/using-env-files-with-nuxt) but I cannot pass NODE_ENV=config.dev (given that config is a file containing the object)  How can I make my app to work like that?

A detailed answered would be helpful.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I Have created one `config.js` same as below

```
const MasterKeys = {
  development: {
    apiEndPoint: 'example.com',
    clientId: '1234567',
    clientSecret: '11111111'
  },
  staging: {
    apiEndPoint: 'staging.example.com',
    clientId: '1234567',
    clientSecret: '11111111'
  },
  production: {
    apiEndPoint: 'prod.example.com',
    clientId: '1234567',
    clientSecret: '11111111'
  }
};

export { MasterKeys };
```

Imported that file in `nuxt.config.js` as below

```
let appEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
import { MasterKeys } from './config.js';
```

Now, whenever I want to use `apiEndPoint` value in nuxt.config.js I will access as `MasterKeys[appEnv].apiEndPoint`

And if I want to use any configuration key from `config.js` in component I will use env property of `nuxt.config.js` as below example.

```
  env: {
    apiEndPoint: MasterKeys[appEnv].apiEndPoint,
    clientId: MasterKeys[appEnv].clientId
  }
```

And then in components, I can access that value as `process.env.apiEndPoint`

And to will declare env in `package.json` as below

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "stagingbuild": "NODE_ENV=staging nuxt build",
    "staging": "NODE_ENV=staging nuxt start",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production nuxt build",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production nuxt start"
  }
```

Hope this will help you!!!!

Comment: what is `[appEnv]`, I see that u created a object but `[appEnv]` is an array syntax?

Comment: let appEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'; in nuxt.config.js declaring environment variable

Comment: Default means when you run `npm run dev` there in package.json we are not providing any `NODE_ENV` so it will take `development` as per our declaration in `nuxt.config.js` for appEnv

Comment: `nuxt.config.js` doesn't let u import statement outside a module.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: so when u use `import { MasterKeys } from './config.js';`outside of module.exports it gives error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module, I think browser doesn't understand import statements?

Comment: which version of `Nuxt` you are using?? In my case it was not giving error I'm on `"nuxt": "2.7.1"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208839/discussion-between-nofel-and-hardik-shah).

Comment: Can we save secret keys in config.js?

Answer (score 4):

I answered the same question here

[How to set custom path for dotenv in nuxt]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71346654/10537000

**If you are using version > 2.13 then you won't need to install dotenv anymore because it's already built in**
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#runtimeconfig

> .env support
> Similar to vue-cli (*), .env file will be always loaded via dotenv and is accessible via process.env and options._env. process.env is updated so one can use it right inside nuxt.config for runtime config. Values are interpolated and expanded with an improved version of dotenv-expand. .env file is also watched to reload during nuxt dev. Path can be set via cli --dotenv  or disabled by --dotenv false.

**I created the .env.xxx files and created the corresponding scripts**

[image: file .env]

[image: file package.json]

Answer (score 1):

Create two separate config files and import them with condition and use inside nuxt config as follows

```
const CONFIG = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? require('dev-config') : require('prod-config');

module.exports = {
  axios: {
    baseURL: CONFIG.API_BASE
  }
}
```

Comment: But it is not just one url, there r bunch of url which need to change depending upon what env will run and how do I use that SERVER in nuxt config?

Comment: when u say require `('dev-config')`, does the file name shld be dev-config.env ?