# How to use Firebase Environment Variables in Nuxt Config

Tags: javascript, firebase, nuxt.js, dotenv

I am trying to separate Firebase Creds from my Nuxt Config file. But it is saying `NuxtServerError Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly.` It works fine when I use my creds directly into my nuxt config (without environment variables).

I am using @nuxtjs/firebase module and this is my config: [firebase ssr/universal auth documentation](https://firebase.nuxtjs.org/tutorials/ssr/)

```
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxtjs/firebase',
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],

  firebase: {
    config: {
      apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
      authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
      databaseURL: process.env.databaseURL,
      projectId: process.env.projectId,
      storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
      messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId,
      appId: process.env.appId,
      measurementId: process.env.measurementId
    },
    services: {
      auth: {
        ssr: true
      }
    }
  },
  pwa: {
    // disable the modules you don't need
    meta: false,
    icon: false,
    // if you omit a module key form configuration sensible defaults will be applied
    // manifest: false,

    workbox: {
      importScripts: [
        // ...
        '/firebase-auth-sw.js'
      ],
      // by default the workbox module will not install the service worker in dev environment to avoid conflicts with HMR
      // only set this true for testing and remember to always clear your browser cache in development
      dev: false
    }
  }
```

I have stored all my creds in `.env` file in my app(with the quotations mark).

```
apiKey="my_key"
authDomain="my_domain"
databaseURL="my_db_url"
projectId="my_project_id"
storageBucket="my_storage_bucket"
messagingSenderId="my_sender_id"
appId="my_app_id"
measurementId="my_measurement_id"
```

Is there any way to separate my creds from nuxt config file (I am committing my nuxt config file on my github).

PS: my environment variables can be console logged from my app component using `process.env.apikey` and others. I also have @nuxtjs/dotenv package installed.

Comment: please check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60483377/4523764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a `@nuxtjs/dotenv` issue (I think).

Regarding to [Using .env file in nuxt.config.js](https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module#using-env-file-in-nuxtconfigjs) documentation, for that case you should use directly `dotenv` module instead of `@nuxtjs/dotenv`.

**`nuxt.config.ts` sample**

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

let path =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
   ? '.env'
   : '.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV

dotenv.config({path})

export default {
 ....
 // Now, you are able to use process.env.<property_from_dotenv>
 env: {
  apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
  databaseURL: process.env.databaseURL,
  projectId: process.env.projectId,
  storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.messagingSenderId,
  appId: process.env.appId,
  measurementId: process.env.measurementId
 },
}
```

**`nuxt.config.js` sample**

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

let path =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
   ? '.env'
   : '.env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV

dotenv.config({path})
```

Comment: sample code https://github.com/rslvn/nuxt-typescript-firebase-auth-ssr

Comment: sorry for some reason, I re-created it with a different name. I removed the multi .env configuration. Using different branches are logically useful in the new repository. But still, you can find extendable infrastructure in  https://github.com/rslvn/nuxt-typescript-ssr-firebase-auth

Answer (score 2):

Nuxt has it own baked environment variable processing. Read about `publicRuntimeConfig: {}` and `privateRuntimeConfig {}` in the docs. You don't need `dotenv` dependency anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue as well.  I use the same setup.

Add :

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

To the top of your nuxt.config.js file. This allows the config to access your local .env file.