# Set development or production api URL from .env in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-cli

For some reason my ternary statement is not working correctly. If I run my Vue Nuxt application like this

***.env***

```
USE_DEV_API='true'
```

***nuxt.config.js***

```
const result = process.env.USE_DEV_API ? process.env.USE_DEV_API + ' true' : process.env.USE_DEV_API + ' false'
```

Result is as expected:

> true true

If I change `USE_DEV_API` in the `.env` to false:

```
USE_DEV_API='false'
```

Result is:

> false true

The strange thing is that if I set the `USE_DEV_API` to false I do get the expected `false false` result:

```
const result = false ? process.env.USE_DEV_API + ' true' : process.env.USE_DEV_API + ' false'
```

Result:

> false false

Comment: Because your env variable is a string which is always truthy?

Comment: Yup, but even when denoted without the single quotes it is still parsed to a string: https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/issues/272 so I just check the string value in the config file. Thanks.

Comment: Non empty strings are truthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `process.env`

This happens because the *.env* variable is set to the *string* `'false'` rather than the keyword `false`.  And all JavaScript strings evaluate to `true` except for the empty string `''`.

This isn't just a matter of having placed quotes in the *.env* file.  The issue is with the way `process.env` works, and you can read it in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env):

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string.

#### Nuxt

Since you are using Nuxt, you already have access to the environment information, and you can use this to automatically select your api:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV  // 'development', 'production'
```

#### Solution

Store just your api URLs in *.env*, for example:

```html
DEV_API=http://mydevapi.com
PROD_API=http://myprodapi.com
```

<sup>(Notice quotes aren't needed since it's all strings anyway.)</sup>

Now you can test the node environment and automatically select the right api:

```
const dev = process.env.DEV_API;
const prod = process.env.PROD_API;
const api = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? dev : prod;
```

This way is better because you don't have to remember to switch your flag every time you build or run in production, because it happens automatically.

Comment: Guys, I did the same thing but when I run `npm run build` or `npm run generate` process.env.NODE_ENV always returns the `production`

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya - Of course, they are both production builds.  Run the development server with `npm run dev`.

Comment: thanks for your revert. its fine but is there any way to handle development, staging, and production?

as currently we are getting `process.env.NODE_ENV = production` on running the `npm run build` or `npm run generate` and got the `development` when we run `npm run dev` but if I need staging is there any way to indicate this?

Comment: @KishanBhensadadiya - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60483377/2185093), note the `package.json` section at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your var env is a string, not a boolean. Th value from `.env` file will always be truthy because it's a string empty or not.

So you can update your test as follows in order to convert the string to boolean:

```js
const result = (process.env.USE_DEV_API === 'true') ? process.env.USE_DEV_API + ' true' : process.env.USE_DEV_API + ' false'
```

For more details see [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)